# PHP - Using one setter on all public properties of a class

Tags: php, oop, properties, getter-setter

There seems to be a lot of questions on setters and getters in PHP. However, none of them seem to mention that they do not work with public variables.

I have a series of public variables, which on setting need the same type of data checking (mainly `strip_tags()`).

What is the most code efficient way to do this whilst keeping the variables ***public***?

The only option which seems to be available is creating a method 'setPropertyName' for all of my variables, which seems unnecessary to me.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I recommend not to use the magic methods, because they're slow. I suggest to mark the field private and write a getter foreach field. Why do you want your fields to be public?

Comment: I want to be able to access them outside the class.

Comment: If this is to only reason, i recommend you to write a public getter and a public setter for each field and mark the field private. This is the common way to do this in php (i almost never have public fields inside a class)

Comment: related: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/propertygetsetsyntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** make them private, and using a public `__set()` and `__get()` to fetch the variables if they exists, and apply the validation/sanitation operations when they set.

For example:

```
class Foo {
    private $variable;
    private $otherVariable;

    public function __get($key) {
        return $this->$key;
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->$key = strip_tags($value);
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->variable = "test"; //Works.
echo $foo->variable; //test
```

Comment: I wanted to do as you have, but with public class properties. Thanks for the help, it seems I should just make my variables private.

Comment: @AdamCarter: If this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is the magic method `__call($name,$args)`, then you wouldn't need to code the setPropertyName and getPropertyName functions:

```
function __call($name,$args){
    $variable=lcfirst(substr($name,3));
    if(!isset($this->$variable))
        return false;
    if(substr($name,0,3)=='set')
        $this->$variable=$args[0];
    else
        return $this->$variable;
    return true;
}
```

That being said, magic methods `__get` and `__set` work great with public variables if utilized properly.  Below is how I utilize them:

```
public $variables=array();
function __get($name){
    return isset($this->variables[$name])?$this->variables[$name]:false;
}
function __set($name,$value){
    $this->variables[$name]=$value;
}
```

Then you can access them by using `$this->name;` rather than `$this->getName();`
Put both of them together and then you can do it however you want.

Again, this is a backbone.  If you want to strip tags, you can put that in the code either in the setter or getter functions, or modify the call function to check for a 2nd argument that will strip the tags `$this->setName($value,true);//strip tags`

Comment: The overloading magic methods such as __set() and __get() are only called when property being accessed is not visible from current scope (i.e. private property and being called outside the class, or protected and being called outside the class or classes that inherit from it). They will not work for public properties.

Comment: Try it, it will work.  I am not accessing $variables directly.  $variables is an array where you store the data.  You can access $variables directly, and the setter and getter will not work.

Comment: `$class->asdf='asdf';` sets just fine and stores it in an array, then you can retrieve it the same way.  You can also access the variable using `$class->variable['asdf'];` if you need to.

Comment: After adding you second example of code it became clearer what your intent was.  I was simply commenting on your statement that magic methods `__get` and `__set` work great with public properties.  They don't work with public properties at all.  If you have a public property and you try to access it, the magic methods will not be called at all.

Comment: I understand, and that is why I would not use it if I wanted to still access individual variables that way.  Either way, we are agreed that it doesn't work with public variables in the `$this->$name` sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually probably best practice to actually explicitly define your getters and setters.  That being said you can use the `__set()` and `__get()` magic methods to provide common handling for requests to properties that are inaccessible from outside the class (protected and private).

So, all you would need to do is make your properties protected/private and specify `__get()` and `__set()` methods (also might need `__isset()` and `__unset()` as well if you will be checking the properties using `isset()` or trying to `unset()` properties).

Again, it is really best practice (IMO) to make all class properties inaccessible from outside the class and explicitly make setters/getters as need to provide access.